# How to move element to the end vertically in grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I need two divs to be at the top of body and one div (blue one) at the bottom of body. All of them must be centered horizontally. I need to do it using grid. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  height: 500px;
  align-content: start;
  justify-content: center;
  background: gray;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  align-self: end;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grid-template-rows` and make the last column take the remaining space using `1fr`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh; /* full heught screen */
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  background: gray;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  align-self: end;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```